# Setting up a shared media drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, directory, permissions

I want to have a shared media drive be transparently usable to all users, whilst also sticking to FHS and Ubuntu standards. The former takes priority if necessary. I currently mount it at `/media/Stuff` but `/media` is supposed to be for external media, i believe. The main issue is setting right permissions so that access to read and write to the drive can be granted to multiple users working within the same directories.

[InstallingANewHardDrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) seems both slightly confused and not what I want. It claims that this sets ownership for the top-level directory (despite the recursion flag):

```
    sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /media/mynewdrive
```

And that this will let multiple users create files and sub-directories but only delete their own:

```
    sudo chgrp plugdev /media/mynewdrive
    sudo chmod g+w /media/mynewdrive
    sudo chmod +t /media/mynewdrive
```

However, the group writeable bit does not seem to get inherited, which is troublesome for keeping things organised (prevents creation inside sub-folders originally made by another user). The sticky bit is probably also unwanted for the same reason, although currently it seems that one userA (perhaps the owner of the mount-point?) can delete the userB's files, but not vice-versa. This is fine, as long as userB can create files inside the directory of userA. So:

- What is the correct mount point?
- Is plugdev the correct group?
- *Most importantly*, how to set up permissions to maintain an organised media drive?

I do not want to be running cron jobs to set permissions regularly!

Comment: What filesystem does the drive use? ext2/ext3/ext4/ntfs?

Answer (score 3):

The correct mount point is */mnt/mynewdrive*; *plugdev* is not correct; on permissions, why not use access control lists (ACL)?

Are the ACL tools installed by default? Can't remember, but, cannot hurt to...

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

Mount the file systems with the acl option in /etc/fstab.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx / ext4 defaults,**acl** 0 1

```
sudo mount -o remount,acl /
```

Then make a group to which a user may belong for this purpose, which I'll call *stone*, and then make a user a member of that group.

```
sudo groupadd stone
sudo usermod -a -G stone $username
```

The user needs to log out and in again to become a member of the group.
If the directory, /mnt/mynewdrive, is mounted and completely empty:

```
sudo chown root.stone /mnt/mynewdrive
sudo chmod 0775 /mnt/mynewdrive
sudo chmod g+s  /mnt/mynewdrive
sudo chmod +t   /mnt/mynewdrive
sudo setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x /mnt/mynewdrive
```

Above...

- Change owner to root and group owner to stone
- Give write ability to the stone group
- Cause all new files to be group-owned by stone
- Restrict delete and rename to all but the user who created the file
- By default, allow user and group rwx, others: rx.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I would suggest setting up a drive without permissions. Use FAT32 or some other non-secure file system and share it over samba.

In the future, I think we need to seriously look at how we enable these kinds of features in Ubuntu.