# List all human users

Tags: command-line, users

How can I list all human users that I've created? I've tried `cat /etc/passwd` and it just lists a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Human users have UIDs starting at 1000, so you can use that fact to filter out the non-humans:

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$' | cut -d: -f1
```

This cuts the first (username) and third (UID) colon-delimited fields from `/etc/passwd`, then filters for the resulting lines which end with a colon and four digits, then cuts the first (username) field from that, leaving you with a list of users with UIDs between 1000 and 9999.

If you have more than nine thousand users on your system, this will fail - but it's necessary to restrict the result to 4-digit UIDs in order not to catch `nobody` (UID 65534).

Answer (score 21):

This does pretty much what [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257451/22949) does, just in one command instead of three:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

And thanks to Karel in the comments, the `nobody` user is also filtered out.

Comment: @karel Yeah, maybe. Instead of filtering by UID, I'm filtering out that username explicitly. There may be a reason for having a legitimate user with a UID that high... Who knows ;)

Answer (score 20):

I personally like to use just:

```
ls /home
```

Admittedly this is not a list of users but instead a list of their home directories. Currently existing human users on the system will have home directories in `/home`, but you may see the home directories of past users who were removed, as well.

This works for my purposes and may work for yours as well. For example, if you are looking to delete a user account that turns out no longer to exist (*`nonexistent-user`*) and run the command

```
sudo deluser nonexistent-user
```

it will just tell you that that this user does not exist.

Comment: +1 This way is simple, it's what most experienced users would actually do, and I think it's no less robust than methods that check a range of UIDs. It seems less likely a human user would have a home directory outside `/home` (that isn't symlinked to `/home`) than that a human user would have a UID of under 1000 (after all, this is the most common method of keeping a display manager from listing a user on the login screen, which may sometimes be done for a human user). The one, relatively minor disadvantage here is that `lost+found` will be listed on systems with separate `/home` partitions.

Comment: Small problem, though: what happens if user was created with `useradd --no-create-home username` ?

Comment: @Serg I think it comes down to the inherent ambiguity in the problem description. Does an account with no home directory really represent a human user? In practice, such accounts are usually--though admittedly not always--used for highly specialized tasks (typically by people with their own separate accounts) or for users intended to access the system only through specific, restricted services. Of course there's another use case for `useradd --no-create-home`--the home directory might already exist or might be created shortly thereafter--but the `ls /home` method works fine for those cases.

Comment: What happens if someone creates a folder not associated with a user or with a human user?
For example a folder for shared files

Answer (score 4):

While it might seem like a clear-cut idea, actually there is ambiguity in the meaning of *human user*. Is a user account deliberately hidden from the login screen because it's used only for specialized purposes (but by humans) a human user? How about the `ubuntu` user (UID 999) on the live CD? And guest accounts in Ubuntu are created on-the-fly and destroyed after logout; are they human users? More examples could be devised.

Therefore, it's fitting that multiple, non-equivalent answers have been given. [Saige Hamblin's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/616604/22949) of running `ls /home` is what people *actually* do, and unless you're writing a script, you should probably just use that.

### Making `ls /home` More Robust

But perhaps you have users that have been removed, but whose home directories still exist in `/home`, and you must avoid listing them. Or maybe for some other reason you must ensure only the entries in `/home` that correspond to real accounts are listed.

In that case, I suggest passing the names of everything in `/home` to [`getent`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/getent.1.html) (to retrieve the `passwd` entries of users with those names), then isolate and display just the username field (with [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/grep.1.html), [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sed.1.html), or [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/gawk.1.html), as per your preference). Any one of these will do:

```bash
getent passwd $(ls /home) | grep -o '^[^:]*'
```

```bash
getent passwd $(ls /home) | sed 's/:.*//'
```

```bash
getent passwd $(ls /home) | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

This should work well, as you shouldn't have user accounts with whitespace or control characters in their names; [cannot, without reconfiguring Ubuntu to allow it](https://askubuntu.com/a/405668/22949); and if you do, you have bigger problems. Thus [the usual problems with parsing `ls` are](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) inapplicable. But even though it's really okay here, if you consider command substitutions with `ls` aesthetically displeasing or just a bad habit, you may prefer:

```bash
getent passwd $(basename -a /home/*) | grep -o '^[^:]*'
```

```bash
getent passwd $(basename -a /home/*) | sed 's/:.*//'
```

```bash
getent passwd $(basename -a /home/*) | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

These don't accommodate whitespace or control characters either. I provide them only because `$(ls /home)` looks wrong even when it is right, and thus rubs many users the wrong way. [In most situations, there are real, good reasons to avoid parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and in those situations parsing `basename -a` is usually only very slightly less bad. In this situation, however, **due to the limitation on what characters may practically occur in usernames**, they are both fine.

### Explanation, Benefits, and Drawbacks

I use `getent` mainly because it accepts usernames as arguments to restrict its output, but also because it is slightly more universal than examining `/etc/passwd` directly, in case authentication facilities and the password database are provided by network services.

This method has the additional benefit over `ls /home` that, on systems with a separate `/home` partition, `lost+found` usually appears in the output of `ls /home`.

- With the more robust method presented above, `lost+found` will only appear if there happens to be a user (human or not) called `lost+found`, which is unlikely.
- But if you're entering commands interactively rather than writing a script, `ls /home` is fine--*you* know you don't have a human user called `lost+found`.

Infrequently, this method (in any of the above variations) will produce unsatisfactory output:

- If a user's home directory exists outside `/home`, or not at all, this suggests but does not imply the account shouldn't be considered to represent a human user. This method only lists users when there is a directory of the same name in `/home`.
- If you have created additional directories in `/home` that aren't actually anybody's home directory, *and* they happen to have the same name as an existing non-human user--or consist of words separated by whitespace, one or more of which has the same name as an existing non-human user--then some non-human users may be included in the output.
  <sub>(This method can be implemented with a loop and separate `getent` invocations, so [word splitting](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) doesn't produce spurious output. But the complexity is not warranted; fundamentally, if you use `/home` as something other than a place for users' home directories, this method will not produce reliable output.)</sub>

---

### Making UID Checking Simpler

If you decide to go with a method that checks user IDs to ensure they are in the likely range for accounts representing human beings, as in [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257451/22949) or [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/329689/22949), then I suggest this for brevity:

```bash
getent passwd | grep -oP '^[^:]+(?=:x:\d{4}:)'
```

This uses a [Perl regular expression](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/perlre.1.html) (`-P`) to show:

- text at the beginning of a line (`^`) containing no `:`s (`[^:]+`) — this is the first field, as `:` is the field separator in `passwd`
- that precedes but doesn't include (`(?=` `)`) the password field `x` — it should always be `x`, since in Ubuntu password hashes are stored in the [`shadow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file) database, not the world-readable `passwd` database
- and a UID field consisting of exactly 4 digits (`:\d{4}:`).

This is thus a significantly shorter and somewhat simpler variant of the technique in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257451/22949). (The technique described there works fine too, and it does have the benefit of being portable to non – GNU/Linux systems whose `grep` doesn't support `-P`.)

### Reconsidering the "Human" UID Range

If you want to accommodate very high UIDs and check for `nobody` explicitly, you can use the method in [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/329689/22949). You may wish to consider, however, if users with very high UIDs should really be assumed human, or if they are more likely to be some other special-purpose non-human user (like `nobody`). In practice such users--besides `nobody`--are uncommon, so really this is a judgment call on your part.

A possible compromise is to list users in the range of UIDs *that are actually being assigned to newly created, non-"system" users.* You can check for this [in `adduser.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/215880/22949):

```
$ grep -E '^(FIRST|LAST)_UID' /etc/adduser.conf
FIRST_UID=1000
LAST_UID=29999
```

Here are two ways to list users whose UIDs range from 1000 to 29999:

```bash
getent passwd | grep -oP '^[^:]+(?=:x:[12]?\d{4}:)'
```

```bash
getent passwd | awk -F: '999<$3 && $3<30000 {print $1}'
```

Comment: If you wanted to be stylistically pleasing, `basename` is ugly. It is no better than `ls`.  The principle reason we don't parse ls is that it is a job that can be done by other tools much more safely and cleanly, *not* style. In this case, the shell: `cd /home; getent passwd *`.

Comment: I agree with you on /home being unreliable (it's useless for me, see my answer). I'm just saying that if you are going to preach about style, expect nitpicking.

Comment: @muru I see how my original phrasing could mislead people to think avoiding parsing `ls` is usually about style. The 2nd bullet point about "unsatisfactory output" covered the issue, but it appears in a later section. I've reworded to clarify why parsing `ls` is appropriate *in this situation*. Although `cd /home; getent passwd *` take a *form* often indicative of a sounder approach, I've avoided it so as not to lead readers to believe the contents of `/home` directories, with weird added entries not corresponding to real users, could still somehow be relied on as a guide to what users exist.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: only human users have SystemAccount=false

One other way is to list output of while ignoring root `ls /var/lib/AccountsService/users/ | grep -v root`. Now, there is a quirk - gdm, a greeter/login screen ( or more formally desktop manager ) is also listed as a user. So just from listing we cant tell if gdm is human or not.

A more efficient and correct approach is to go through the files in that folder and find out which users are listed as having `SystemAccount=false`. The one-liner bellow achieves that

`grep SystemAccount=false /var/lib/AccountsService/users/* | awk -F '/' '{gsub(":","/");print $6}'`

Comment: Although sometimes handy, this fails in some relatively common scenarios. For example, on my Ubuntu 15.04 minimal system (installed from `mini.iso` and with no display managers or X11 installed), I have one human user account--yet `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` is an empty directory. I expect this will similarly not work on an out-of-the-box Ubuntu Server installation. Furthermore, when this does work, it does so under a somewhat restrictive notion of what makes a user account "human": making a user with `useradd`, even *without* `--system`, doesn't create a file in `AccountsService/users`.

Answer (score 1):

Joining the party, I oversee a network systems using LDAP, having home directories outside `/home` and UIDs (due to a scripting glitch) in the millions. None of the current answers, therefore, work. The test that works for me is checking whether the user has a valid login shell. A valid shell is one which is listed in [`/etc/shells`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shells.5). The simplest form:

```
getent passwd | grep -wFf /etc/shells
```

The file may contain comments (or empty lines), so one might have to filter them out:

```
getent passwd | grep -wFf <(grep '^/' /etc/shells)
```

Comment: +1 This may be the most robust approach suggested so far. Although it has the disadvantage of showing `root` (which *probably* shouldn't be considered a human user, since humans usually become root temporarily and for specific purposes, rather than using it for their regular work), it seems like it's the least likely to fail in any major way. The methods in other answers (including mine) may fail, depending on the method, if home directories aren't in `/home`, other garbage *is* in `/home`, UIDs are weird, or the system doesn't use a DM. This answer works pretty well in all those scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

On buntu systems, regular users (human users, that is) have UIDs beginning with 1000 which are assigned sequentially to them when their accounts are first created. What all this boils down to is that the first account created on a buntu system has a UID of 1000. The next one created has a UID of 1001. And so on and so forth.

So, the simplest way to list all human user accounts present on the system, in my opinion, is to check whether the third column in the `/etc/passwd` file which contains the user's UID is greater than or equal to 1000 and less than, let's say, 2000 (it's very unlikely for a typical desktop PC to have more than one thousand user accounts, don't you think so?):

```
$ awk -F$':' '{ if ($3 >= 1000 && $3 < 2000) print $1; }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining Oli's answer with details. You also need to filter out `nobody`. =)

Comment: You don't have to because nobody has a UID of 65534 and thus is automatically filtered out as all other nonhuman user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E "x:[1-9]([0-9]){3}:" /etc/passwd
```

It browses the content of /etc/passwd looking for entries of human users.

To do that grep looks for lines that have user id numbers bigger than 1000.

Examples of matching regex:

x:1001:

x:1203: