# What is the purpose of the 'nobody' user?

Tags: users, username, switch-user

After I read [List all human users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257421/list-all-human-users) I noticed that there is a user account named 'nobody' in my Ubuntu system.

Also I noticed that I can login in this account from terminal using the following command and my password:

```
sudo su nobody
```

[image: su nobody]

It doesn't mind me at all, but I want to know what is the purpose of this user? Is it created by default on a fresh install of Ubuntu or is created by installing a particular package?

Comment: Note that when you log in using your password, you're using your password for the sudo step, not for the nobody account (and that the reason it works is because the superuser can su to anyone without needing to enter their password (although as mentioned below, I believe at least on RH-derivatives, if nobody's shell is set to /sbin/nologin, you still wouldn't be able to log in even using superuser (aka root)

Comment: That's the case by default now (18.04+?). `sudo su nobody` return _This account is currently not available._ because the shell for the user `nobody` [is set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`](https://askubuntu.com/a/486661/349837) (`getent passwd nobody`).

Comment: @sarnold - please see my comment on the answer I believe you're alluding at. It's a rather poor answer, as it doesn't reason or cite sources. It furthermore goes counter to all I know about the nobody account and how NFS works: with `root_squash` on it will **map root to nobody** on remote systems. This is more or less exactly the opposite of what [this answer states](https://askubuntu.com/a/674397/653515)

Comment: Posting images of text causes severe accessibility problems. Especially for blind people. But also to others.

Comment: I just had a use case for this user: On a web interface that is controlling a program on my computer, I can specify a command line that is used to process some data (typically `grep`, `sed`...). I don't want this feature to be a too large security risk (e.g. specify `rm *` as "text processing" command)... Running `grep` or `sed` as user "nobody" eliminates this risk.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It's there to run things that don't need any special permissions. It's usually reserved for vulnerable services (httpd, etc) so that if they get hacked, they'll have minimal damage on the rest of the system.

Contrast this with running something *as* a real user, if that service were compromised (web servers are occasionally exploited to run arbitrary code), it would run as that user and have access to everything that user had. In most cases, this is *as bad* as getting root.

You can read a little bit more about the nobody user on the Ubuntu Wiki:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/nobody

To answer your follow-ups:

#### Why I can't access this account with `su nobody`?

`sudo grep nobody /etc/shadow` will show you that nobody doesn't have a password and you can't `su` without an account password. The cleanest way is to `sudo su nobody` instead. That'll leave you in a pretty desolate `sh` shell.

#### Can you give a *particular example* when is indicated to use this account?

When permissions aren't required for a program's operations. This is most notable when there isn't ever going to be any disk activity.

A *real world* example of this is `memcached` (a key-value in-memory cache/database/thing), sitting on my computer and my server running under the nobody account. Why? Because it just doesn't need any permissions and to give it an account that did have write access to files would just be a needless risk.

Comment: Just two more things if you can explain: 1) why I can't access this account with `su nobody` and 2) can you give *a particular example* when is indicated to use this account?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu 1) I'm guessing that's because it doesn't have a password set, and when you `su` as an ordinary user, you must give the target user's password. Try `sudo -i` then `su nobody` from the root shell (which won't require a password).

Comment: `Network File System` maps `root` to `nobody` so local root cannot access everything like the remote root can.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I've edited to pull in and answer your questions.

Comment: @Demizey , @Braiam , @Githlar Have you tested this command: `sudo -u nobody -i`?

Comment: Ah, crap, it works on some systems, but it's nonstandard. The old one wont work either, the -i needs to be replaced with a shell.

Comment: @Demizey The old one works perfect. See the OP's picture.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Doesn't work for me and for a lot of other people because normally nobody doesn't have a default shell.

Comment: @Demizey In Ubuntu, because about Ubuntu we speak here, `nobody` user has and always had a default shell - it's `/bin/sh`, as Oli said in his answer.

Comment: @Oli Now you contradict yourself in the answer: *The cleanest way is to `sudo -u nobody /bin/bash` instead. That'll leave you in a pretty desolate `sh` shell*. In my opinion, if `/bin/bash` was used, that'll leave you in a `bash` shell. Furthermore, when I run `sudo -u nobody /bin/bash`, this will give me an error `bash: /home/radu/.bash_aliases: Permission denied`. So, I suppose that is not the cleanest way.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Please note the edit history. When I tested the original command (not what's there) this originally I was ending up in a dash (/bin/sh) shell but I can't replicate that now. Your original edit was fine. It wasn't me who changed it.

Comment: @Oli But you've accepted it :D Also you can clean all these useless comments if you feel so.

Comment: IMPORTANT: The user 'nobody' must NEVER own any files, nor have write access to anything. If either `find / -user nobody` or `find / -group nogroup` return any files your system is VULNERABLE.

Comment: @Born2Smile Why? And vulnerable to what? How?

Comment: @Oli, The whole idea behind 'nobody'-user is to run vulnerable (or potentially vulnerable) processes from it. Thus, when such a process is hacked the hacker will gain access to the system as 'nobody'. If at that point 'nobody' owns any files or folders the hacker will be allowed to edit those files and folders, thus compromising any systems relying on those files. A scary example of this is npm (node.js package manager). npm will by default install all files as 'nobody', thus someone who gains access as 'nobody' to your machine will have full "admin" rights to all of your node.js-server setup.

Comment: @Born2Smile I don't disagree. You've just rephrased the opening paragraph of this answer... But the account owning files doesn't mean the system is vulnerable, it means that if a service running as nobody is hacked, those files are vulnerable. That's a very big difference.

Comment: @Oli, indeed you mentioned something to this effect in your first paragraph, however IME few people realise that the increased security of processes doesn't apply to files owned by 'nobody'. Having files or folders owned by 'nobody' makes your system __less__ secure, not more. Also you needn't be hacked, say you have an anonymous ftp-server on your machine (intended for people to download stuff from you) this would run as 'nobody' specifically to prevent people from getting too much access, however if any folders are owned by 'nobody', anyone would also be allowed to upload to those folders.

Comment: I always thought `nobody` is actually/primarily used by NFS as [linuxstandardbase](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/usernames.html) states.

Comment: -1: `nobody` is strictly for NFS and should not be used by other services and certainly not by system administrators. Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu man claims: [Some misguided programs or guides suggest that this user should be used for untrusted program execution or handling untrusted data. This is bad advice.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/nobody) On QNAP NAS, uid 65534 is user Guest and there is no nobody (there also in no root, but "admin"). Files belonging to guest are shown as belonging to nobody on QTV and other docker/containers running on that NAS. Files created as guest on Samba will be owned 65534, guest/nobody. Seems to be a bit of a confusion about this uid.

Answer (score 55):

#### The user nobody is reserved for [NFS only](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/usernames.html).

The anwers above are rather wrong, because they assume that `nobody` is a "generic" anonymous/guest style user id.

In the UNIX/Linux access control model anonymous/guest style user ids don't exist and these are bad suggestions:

- "*common to run daemons as `nobody`, especially servers, in order to limit the damage that could be done by a malicious user who gained control of them.*" because of the that follows: "*However, the usefulness of this technique is reduced if more than one daemon is run like this, because then gaining control of one daemon would provide control of them all*".
- "*A real world example of this is `memcached` (a key-value in-memory cache/database/thing), sitting on my computer and my server running under the `nobody` account. Why? Because it just doesn't need any permissions and to give it an account that did have write access to files would just be a needless risk.*"

The `nobody` user name with user id 65534 was created and reserved for a specific purpose and should be used only for that purpose: as a placeholder for "unmapped" users and user ids in NFS tree exports.

That is, unless user/id mapping is setup for NFS tree exports, *all* files in the export will appear owned by `nobody`. The purpose of this is to prevent all users on the importing system from accessing those files (unless they have "other" permissions), as none of them (except `root`) can be/become `nobody`.

Therefore it is a very bad idea to use `nobody` for **any** other purpose, because its purpose is to be a user name/user id for files that must not be accessible to anybody.

The generic Wikipedia entry is very wrong too. Compare it with the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/nobody).

The UNIX/Linux practice is to create a new account for each "application" or application area that needs a separate access control domain, and to **never reuse `nobody` outside NFS**.

Comment: This answer does not cite any sources, and explicitly contradicts several of the other answers, which *do* cite sources. The current bounty indicates this answer is particularly good, in which case it *should* cite some sources, or at list have some reasoning.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/nobody , http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/usernames.html

Comment: @mook765 That part is fine. The paragraph about NFS however, I do not grok. For instance with `root_squash` on, `root` is mapped to the user `nobody`, so files having owner `nobody` would make absolutely no sense. In addition the statement that files owned by nobody is meant to be inaccessible to anyone makes little sense, as file permissions are separate from ownership in UNIX. I'm not saying that everything in the answer is wrong, just that elements of it makes little or no sense to me :)

Comment: @vidarlo, this answer isn't suggesting that you should set files to be owned by `nobody`. It's telling you that `nobody` is for NFS to use when mapping permissions, and that's the most important point to me. *How* NFS uses `nobody` is less interesting than the fact that it *does* use `nobody`. Thanks.

Comment: @sarnold the answer is still plain wrong in this matter in my opinion. If a user reads the answer and `man exports`, he may be very confused.

Comment: Well, at least Solaris (the system from which NFS originated!) **was** using `nobody` for multiple purposes, not only for NFS - for example for running web server.

Answer (score 30):

> In many Unix variants, "nobody" is the conventional name of a user
>   account which owns no files, is in no privileged groups, and has no
>   abilities except those which every other user has.
>
> It is common to run daemons as nobody, especially servers, in order to
>   limit the damage that could be done by a malicious user who gained
>   control of them. However, the usefulness of this technique is reduced
>   if more than one daemon is run like this, because then gaining control
>   of one daemon would provide control of them all. The reason is that
>   nobody-owned processes have the ability to send signals to each other
>   and even debug each other, allowing them to read or even modify each
>   other's memory.

Information taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_(username).

Comment: -1: `nobody` is strictly for NFS and should not be used by other services and certainly not by system administrators. Thanks.

Comment: The citation is outdated now.

Answer (score 18):

The `nobody` user is created by default on a fresh install (checked on Ubuntu Desktop 13.04).

> In many *nix variants, **`nobody`** is the conventional name of a user
>   account which owns no files, is in no privileged groups, and has no
>   abilities except those which every other user has (the `nobody` user
>   and group do not have any entry in the `/etc/sudoers` file).
>
> It is common to run *daemons* as `nobody`, especially servers, in
>   order to limit the damage that could be done by a malicious user who
>   gained control of them. However, the usefulness of this technique is
>   reduced if more than one daemon is run like this, because then gaining
>   control of one daemon would provide control of them all. The reason is
>   that `nobody`-owned processes have the ability to send signals to each
>   other and even debug each other, allowing them to read or even modify
>   each other's memory.
>
> <sub>**Source**:
>   [Wikipedia - Nobody (username)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_%28username%29)</sub>

---

> The `nobody`-owned processes are able to send signals to each others
>   and even ptrace each other in Linux, meaning that a nobody-owned
>   process can read and write the memory of another nobody-owned process.
>
> This is a sample entry of the `nobody` user in the `/etc/passwd` file:
>
> ```
> alaa@aa-lu:~$ grep nobody /etc/passwd
> nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
> ```
>
> As you may notice, the `nobody` user has `/bin/sh` as a login shell
>   and `/nonexistent` as the home directory. As the name suggests, the
>   `/nonexistent` directory does not exist, by default.
>
> If you are paranoid, you can set `nobody`’s default shell as
>   `/usr/sbin/nologin` and so, deny the ssh login for the `nobody` user.
>
> <sub>**Source**:
>   [LinuxG.net - The Linux and Unix Nobody User](http://linuxg.net/the-linux-and-unix-nobody-user/)</sub>

Comment: This answer would deserve a +1 if the incorrect paragraph from Wikipedia were removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

nobody is a special user and group account. Because it is an actual username (and groupname) and can be used by processes and even users, it is not literally *nobody*. For example, some Apache configurations have nobody as the user/group that owns the website files and directories. The problem comes when multiple processes might use the nobody user, such as NFS directories and the webserver.

Answer (score 4):

Minor correction to the '**The user nobody is reserved for NFS only.**' answer. The `nobody` user is also used for unprivileged containers with bind mounts at this time.

This is taken from systemd-nspawn, specifically the --bind mount option:

> Note that when this option is used in combination with
>   --private-users, the resulting mount points will be owned by the nobody user. That's because the mount and its files and directories
>   continue to be owned by the relevant host users and groups, which do
>   not exist in the container, and thus show up under the wildcard UID
>   65534 (nobody). If such bind mounts are created, it is recommended to
>   make them read-only, using --bind-ro=.

[systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)