# Separate system users and service users

Tags: user-management

We all know that we have system users and service users. I am looking for a way to separate them as system users and service user list.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Based on `gid`, system users and service users can be separated** as follows,

`/etc/passwd` contains list for all users along with some other information. Service users or real users have `gid` greater than or equals to 1000. So a list of real users can be obtained as,

```bsh
awk -F: '($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Also a list of system users (`gid` < 1000) can be extracted as,

```bsh
awk -F: '($3<1000){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

**How it works**

The contents of `/etc/passwd` are like,

```
    root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
    ...
    souravc:x:1001:1001:Souravc:/home/souravc:/bin/bash
```

When using `awk` with `-F:` it splits the contents of a line into several fields treating `:` as field separator. First field contains the user name and third field has the `gid`.

Hence to extract real users `awk` just check value of third field is greater than equals to 1000 and it is not [nobody user](https://askubuntu.com/q/329714/127327) and prints the first field i.e., the user name.

To list all system users it just checks `gid` is less than 1000 and prints the user name.

**Edit**

As you want to list `root`(gid = 0) in real user list. Get real users as,

```bsh
awk -F: '($3==0)||($3>=1000)&&($1!="nobody"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Get system users as,

```bsh
awk -F: '($3<1000)&&($1!="root"){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

**Note** I am always ignoring `nobody` user.

Comment: How it can take care of root user ?

Comment: did not understand your point? you will get root as system user. do you wish to include root in real user list?

Comment: yes because he is also user.

Comment: @rajagenupula is it ok now?

Comment: I would like to have root user in real user list @S

Comment: @rajagenupula please try my edits

Answer (score 2):

To list local (system users) than can login and have homedir and GID less than 1000

```
 cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 1,3,6 | grep "[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" | grep "/home" | cut -d: -f1
```

To list all other users:(mainly system users and have GID less than 1000):

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 1,3,6 | grep -v "[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"  | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Root user's group ID and user's ID is less than 1000 right.thank you for answer

Comment: @rajagenupula yes for sure. only root is the exception. and in ubuntu generally, root cannot login by default.

Answer (score 0):

Actual users (other than root) on a nix system should have a home directory identified. So, to find all of those users and root:

```
cat /etc/passwd | egrep '/root|/home' | cut -d":" -f1
```