# "This account is currently not available" error when trying to ssh

Tags: ssh

An error occurs when I try to make SSH connection:

```
$ ssh -p 22 www-data@x.x.x.x 
This account is currently not available
```

Comment: This may be relevant in some cases : [Executing a command as a nologin user](https://serverfault.com/questions/333321/executing-a-command-as-a-nologin-user).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You're getting the `This account is currently not available.` error because the shell for the user `www-data` is set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, and it's set for a very good reason. You should not log in as `www-data`, it's a special user/group used by the web server, not intended for regular shell use.

**EDIT**: It is an **especially bad idea** to give `sudo` rights to `www-data`. If Apache was intended to run with root permissions, it wouldn't have it's own group. By doing this, you are creating huge security holes. You have been warned.

Comment: That's not very constructive. What information do you think I should add to make this answer better?

Comment: @kraxor is correct but if you must you can login as root and change /usr/sbin/nologin in /etc/passwd to /bin/bash and it'll grant that user shell access. I do this when just running a snap binary as my webserver. www-data is generally reserved for nginx/apache on ubuntu hence the no login status.

Comment: @RyanNerd It's your choice not to "give a rat's a$$ about security crap". Running everything as root [is not recommended](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7909622) even inside Docker. You could of course configure Apache to run as `root`, or add a login shell to `www-data`, but that's like opening a bottle of wine by breaking the bottle because you're too lazy and careless to use a cork-screw.

Comment: @kraxor your link to docker is out of date. [EVERYTHING is still owned by root in Docker and it is still a problem](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6119).

Comment: I have a similar case. I want to run LibreOffice in headless mode in a way that it can be called by a PHP script to convert documents and that it can write files to disk as www-data because these files later need to be deleted by www-data (part of a PHP script) to clean them up.

This (launching an headless LibreOffice as user www-data) used to work in previous versions of Ubuntu, and I understand that this is a security improvement over these earlier versions.

Comment: I solved it like this: 
- I create a new user, 
- add it to the group www-data and launch the LibreOffice instance with this user,
- then set the permissions for the base directory through PHP (I had to use umask(0) in PHP to avoid a tricky umask that always reduced my folder access to 0755 which prevented the new user to create a file there), 
- call the conversion process, 
- then treat the file with PHP 
- and finally delete the directory

This is working fine as a replacement to the previous launching as www-data.

Comment: If you set `/bin/sh` for www-data user then exploited the security right ?

Comment: most likely there is a www-data group as well. Create a user and add them to that www-date group. Then everything is chown by www-data:www-data  and you can log in as your newly created user and have the group permission.

Answer (score 158):

While I agree with the others that allowing login through SSH through the www-data user is generally a bad idea, once you've logged in with a normal user it may be useful to run multiple commands concurrently with the permissions set of the www-data user. In that case, one can run

```
sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash
```

and you will be able to access your files as the www-data user.

Comment: Very useful for debugging permissions for a daemon/service user

Comment: you just saved my day thanks! I had trouble getting perl-fcgi service started because the startup script was not using `-s /bin/bash`

Comment: maybe it has a siple way to make `git pull` without `su - www-data`?
and generate rsa key for `www-data` user

Comment: Very useful to check the crontab of the www-data, who can contain code inserted by bots if your website is not totally secure (in my case Laravel debug mode vulnerability).

Answer (score -2):

The first question I would have to ask is, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

kraxor is 100% correct you should never be able to ssh into your server using your Apache/Nginx user. Doing so invites every hacker with half a brain cell into your server.

If you need to run a script or some program as that user you could try `sudo -u www-data yourscript` or you could temporally `chown` on the file to a user with login privileges. It's just a vary bad idea to allow this account that kind of access.

Comment: You should know that `su -` doesn't work for accounts with disable login.

Comment: What account is disabled? It says nothing about the account being disabled

Comment: Well having nologin in passwd means disabled login :)

Comment: It's a service account not a disabled account, you can run commands under it

Comment: My server doesn't appear to know that distinction @TheStarvingGeek

Comment: And it still doesn't. Always fun to find your own comment when looking for an answer years later.