# SSH Connexion configuration

Tags: ssh

I'm managing a several servers which are in Linux. I will have others administrators who will need access to those servers in order to administrate them.
So I would like to have a sort of `ssh` bastion which will transparently connect users to these servers via `ssh` from their laptop which are in windows.
I don’t want to copy the users public keys on my remote servers.
I would like to have all the public keys of remote servers in a repository on the `ssh` bastion. Is this possible?

If yes, what are the configurations do to to have this?

Comment: What do you mean by "ssh bastion"? The most secure approach would indeed be to put the users public keys on the server, anything else would be a security nightmare (from a sysadmin POV).

Comment: Are the user's certificates signed by your own CA? In that case, the servers could validate the certificates, no need to predistribute. You would still have to manage users, though.

Comment: I mean by "ssh bastion" a sorte of proxy ssh which will be the intermediate between remote servers and hosts who will will to ssh to the remote servers

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative: keep all your clients' SSH keys on one server, and the configure your servers to ask that server for authorized SSH keys. This can be done using the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` directive in [`sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

From the manpage:

```
 AuthorizedKeysCommand
         Specifies a program to be used to look up the user's public keys.
         The program must be owned by root and not writable by group or
         others.  It will be invoked with a single argument of the
         username being authenticated, and should produce on standard
         output zero or more lines of authorized_keys output (see
         AUTHORIZED_KEYS in sshd(8)).  If a key supplied by
         AuthorizedKeysCommand does not successfully authenticate and
         authorize the user then public key authentication continues using
         the usual AuthorizedKeysFile files.  By default, no
         AuthorizedKeysCommand is run.

 AuthorizedKeysCommandUser
         Specifies the user under whose account the AuthorizedKeysCommand
         is run.  It is recommended to use a dedicated user that has no
         other role on the host than running authorized keys commands.
```

The command can be simply a script with:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
ssh bastion "cat $HOSTNAME/$1/authorized_keys"
```

Here the server's `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser` has a key-based (passwordless) login, and simply outputs the `authorized_keys` file for the hostname/user combination from the keyserver. Another way would be:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
wget --post-data="host=$HOSTNAME&user=$1" https://bastion
```

where the keyserver runs an HTTP server which returns a set of authorized keys based on the hostname and user. A one-file PHP or Python script would be sufficient to process such a form. An advantage would be that using a database server like PostgreSQL or MySQL would be easier. (Of course, you don't *need* to use the hostname.)

This method is most commonly used with LDAP, I think. There are a couple of scripts for LDAP: http://www.sysadmin.org.au/index.php/2012/12/authorizedkeyscommand/ and http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/1562 that you can look at.

---

To set this up, in the servers, create a user (call it `authkeys`) to run the the command (or you can use the [`nobody`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329714/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-nobody-user) user):

```
adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --shell /usr/sbin/nologin authkeys
```

On the intermediate server (call it `bastion`), a slightly different command: we will set shell to `/bin/bash` for convenience (but you can limit that):

```
adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --shell /bin/bash authkeys
```

This very unprivileged user will be used for the sole purpose of connecting to the intermediate server and getting the keys.
Create a script that this user will run:

```
sudo tee -a /usr/local/bin/get_keys.sh <<"EOF"
#! /bin/bash
ssh bastion "cat $HOSTNAME/$1/*.pub 2>/dev/null"
EOF
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/get_keys.sh
```

Edit the SSH server configuration `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the servers and add:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/bin/get_keys.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser authkeys
```

And restart the SSH servers:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Then, for simplicity, generate an SSH key pair and use the same keypair on all servers for `authkeys` user:

```
# On one server
ssh-keygen -N '' -f id_rsa
```

On all the other servers, copy these `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files created by the above command, then add them to the `authkeys` user's SSH configuration:

```
cp id_rsa* ~authkeys/.ssh/
sudo chown authkeys:authkeys .ssh -R
sudo chmod 0700 .ssh
chmod 0600 .ssh/*
```

On the intermediate server, add this key to the `authorized_keys` list:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~authkeys/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Finally, on the intermediate serves, make a directory structure following the script we used above:

```
mkdir -p ~authkeys/some_host/some_login
```

Then add the authorized keys of your administrators to the directory:

```
echo "some_key" > ~authkeys/some_host/some_login/admin1.pub
echo "some_other_key" > ~authkeys/some_host/some_login/admin2.pub
```

Chown everything to root (or your user - but anything other than `authkeys`):

```
chown root:root ~authkeys/* -R
chmod o=rx ~authkeys/*/* 
chmod o=r ~authkeys/*/*/*.pub -R
```

Use hostnames or IPs, but remember to change the script to use the appropriate value.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. I think your method is great. So, in my "intermediate" server, I have I lot of users account, and each user has his own key pair. I would be ok to take the first option with the ssh bastion "cat $HOSTNAME/$1/authorized_keys". But whaat are the exact configurations in remote servers side and the intermediate?

Comment: @DiarraDiagne perhaps I should clarify: your users would still be connecting to the servers directly.

Comment: yes that will be the goal

Comment: I would like for example to be connected to a remote server only by typing ssh login@Ip_server

Comment: @DiarraDiagne I have updated the answer with instructions.

Comment: .Thanks a lot for your answers. Let me try it and update you back

Comment: But where do I have to add the following script? on remote servers? on the intermediate? or in both of them              sudo tee -a /usr/local/bin/get_keys.sh <<"EOF"
#! /bin/bash
ssh bastion "cat $HOSTNAME/$1/*.pub 2>/dev/null"
EOF
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/get_keys.sh

Comment: @DiarraDiagne Since that creates the script to be run as the `AuthorizedKeysCommand`, it should be in the remote servers.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but finally, It will be the same as putting the public keys of users in different remote servers in order to have direct connection. Ideally, I would like to have all the remote servers public keys in the intermediate server instead of having users public keys on it

Comment: Do you have any idea on it?