# How to give all the users(except guest) permissions to particular directory via terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I want every user to have full permissions over a single directory(and all the contents). Is this possible, and how? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the guest session account or did you create a separate guest user account?

Comment: It's not a big deal if a guset has acces to this folder, but it's better that it doesn't. I mean real guest account, which you get when you install ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want to with **adding users in particular group** and then **applying full permission to that group**.

(`echo $USER` & `echo $LOGNAME` is helpful to get username and logname)

### Example:

If/Let:

`dir1` is directory to which you want to apply full permission to user,
 `user1` is user to which you want to give full permission,
 `group1` is existing or to be create for giving full permission.

**Then following command-line information can help you:**

1. `group1` can be created using following command:

   ```
   sudo addgroup group1
   ```
2. `user1` can be added to `group1` using following command:

   ```
   sudo adduser pandya group1
   ```
3. Now permissions can be applied using following commands:

   ```
   sudo chown :group1 -R dir1
   sudo chmod g+rwx group1
   ```

### Explanation:

- `sudo chown :group1 -R dir1` will apply **`group1` to `dir1`** **recursively** by `-R` (to all sub directories and files)
- `sudo chmod g+rwx group1` will apply **read+write+execution permission to `group1`**
- **As `user1` is in `group1` so-that now `user1` has full permission via `group1` for `dir1` recursively!**

### Verification:

```
$ ls -ld dir1
drwxrwxr-x 3 pandya group1 4096 Aug  3 12:11 example
```

where `drwxrwxr-x` indicates `d` for directory 1st `rwx` for owner(`u=pandya`)  permission 2nd **`rwx` for group(`g=group1`) permission** and `r-x` for other(o) permission in **`ugo`** manner.

Answer (score 4):

As the `guest session` user does not get added to the `users` group you could simply do the following:

`sudo chown -R $USER:users /var/privatefolder`

`sudo chmod -R 770 /var/privatefolder`

The guest session user could then not access the contents of `/var/privatefolder`

### Edit

Looks like users created in GUI or at installation are not added to Users group automatically. I assumed this to be true.

you would have to `sudo usermod -a -G users username`

This would need you to add users to the group manually thus making this answer by [TuKsn](https://askubuntu.com/a/505936/21436) just as easy.

Comment: I enter this and I cannot see the contents of directory. Please, help.

Comment: You as in the user? or you as in the Guest. can you please show the output of `ls -l /path/to/folder`

Comment: ls: cannot open directory /opt/D3GO/: Permission denied

Comment: `ls -l /opt/ | grep D3GO`

Comment: drwxrwx--- 5 root users 4096 авг  2 20:24 D3GO

Comment: @TuKsn good catch

Comment: @DusanMilosevic try **`sudo chown -R $USER:users /opt/D3GO/`** instead of `sudo chown -R $user:users /opt/D3GO/`

Comment: I'm afraid this only works for me, and not other users. Thank you.

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: Are your other users members of the "users" group? or were they created with `useradd` and not added to users group.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic You can run this to add all your "human" user to the users group: `for u in $(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd); do sudo usermod -a -G users $u; done` based on: http://askubuntu.com/a/329689/265974

Comment: They were created the GUI way...

Comment: @TuKsn This works, thank you. So, the combination of your answers solves the problem. I don't know whose answer to accept... Thank you very much!

Comment: I just tested this morning and it looks like users are not automatically added to the users group on creation with the GUI or even at installation. This seems incredible to me. You should accept @TuKsn as his a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group for all the user which should have access to this folder.

Create a new group:

```
sudo groupadd myNewGroup
```

Add a user to the group

```
sudo usermod -a -G myNewGroup username
```

Change user and group of the directory

```
sudo chown -R $USER:myNewGroup /path/to/dir/
```

Change the permissions of the directory

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/dir/
```

Or `ug+rwx` more info for permissions http://permissions-calculator.org/

**Edit**: As Shutupsquare suggest you can use the group users which already exists.
To add all human users to the group you can use:

```
for u in $(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd); do sudo usermod -a -G users $u; done
```

based on: https://askubuntu.com/a/329689/265974

Comment: The problem is that I "don't know" the username as I intend to use this on a multiple computers with different usernames. If the guest can access the directory, that's actually not a problem.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: In that case you can simply make the directory "world writable": `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir` That won't automatically give write access to files created by other users, but everyone would be able to read everything.

Comment: If it is not really necessary I would avoid 777 ...

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I usually suggest either, but to me it sounds like it's what @DusanMilosevic asks for.