# How to list "loginnable" users?

Tags: login, users, user-management, passwd

When I start Ubuntu there is a list of users I can click and enter the password for to log in.

How do I get a list of these users?

I tried to get users from the `/etc/passwd` file by doing this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort -u
```

But this list was huge, nothing like the small list that shows up in the initial login screen.

Is there some other command or file I should be checking?

Comment: log in how ? You can run `sudo passwd -aS` to see the status of users, but users may be able to log in via ssh or Kerberos or even connect via VNC.

Comment: You mean [human users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257421/list-all-human-users)

Comment: While the answers here work for typical desktop scenarios take care that they have potential flaws as they are based on UID and do not take certain uncommon logins such as ssh and thus may not detect accounts created or modified by crackers. See https://serverfault.com/questions/576071/how-do-you-tell-if-a-user-is-allowed-to-log-in-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Users created with `useradd` have a UID of 1000–60000, see

```
$ grep "^UID_M*" /etc/login.defs
UID_MIN                  1000
UID_MAX                 60000
```

With this information we can filter `/etc/passwd` for these users:

```
$ awk -F: '$3 >= 1000' /etc/passwd
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
dessert:x:1000:1000:dessert,,,:/home/dessert:/bin/bash
test:x:1001:1001:test,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

`-F:` sets `:` as the field delimiter and `$3 >= 1000` tells `awk` to just print lines where the third column contains a value equal to or greater than `1000`. Now we only want the username and `nobody` isn't relevant for us, so let's trim the output even more:

```
$ awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
dessert
test
```

Now we also (`&&`) test for the first column to not be (`!=`) the string `nobody` and only print the first column (`print $1`).

Answer (score 0):

Loginable users must have a valid hashed password.  Look at the second field (delimited by colons :) in the /etc/shadow file and the hashes are big, 60+ characters.  The fields with just an * or a ! cannot be login users.  Amusingly, the uuid check is improperly used on libvirt-qemu (64055 uuid), so it shows up on the login screen, even though it does not have a valid hash, and cannot be used as a login name.
Produce the login list with:

```
sudo egrep -v ":\*:|:\!:" /etc/shadow
```

Comment: I get `bash: ": unrecognized history modifier` when I try this

Comment: Also doesn't seem to be fully accurate since I can `useradd` someone new, not give them a password, and they show up in the login screen but simply have no usable password since they have `!` in the /etc/shadow file. Meanwhile "root" has the same password `!` and yet does not show up in the login screen.

Comment: Sorry, lost a backslash before the !, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `loginable` users we can use the `/etc/passwd` file since every user with a `UID` greater than `499` and that does not match the configuration settings in `/etc/lightdm/user.conf` will appear on the login screen. Hence this will get these users:

```
cut -d: -f1-3 /etc/passwd | grep -E ".*:x:[0-9]{4,}" | grep -Ev "nobody"
```

Or using a more concise `awk` code as suggested by @dessert

```
awk -F: '$3>999&&$1!="nobody" { print $1" "$3 }' /etc/passwd
```

`Awk` explanation:

`-F:`: Use `:` as the field separator

`$3>999&&$1!="nobody"`: return values that match `3rd` field that's greater than `999` and 1st field which does not match string `nobody`

An example is user `nobody` with minimum `UID` above `500` but is not seen on the login screen since it's listed as `user` that should not be as seen in the `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`