# exlude users from display manager

Tags: lightdm, gdm, unity-greeter

I just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. To not break anything, I created the default user during install, but I neither need nor want it. I added my usual users (UIDs > 10000), which work great.

Now I want to remove the user that I created during the installation from the greeter.

Using `gdm` I would usually put

```
[greeter]
Exclude = dummy
```

into `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` as [described on the gnome homepage](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en). When using `lightdm`, I would use its minimum-uid setting in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` like this:

```
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=1001 #1100 10000 11000  <-- other attempts
```

as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/q/211087/300811) and reading the comments in `users.conf` this is also very intuitive.

However, it would seem `gdm` and `lightdm` couldn't care less about my configuration settings. The users set up on this system will change so I would rather use the facilities to exclude certain users, rather than keeping the display manager configurations up to date.

How can I make Ubuntu care for my display manager settings? Do I need to enable this somewhere?

I even went tried the Windows way of rebooting a few times ...

As a next step I will delete this default user, but I don't know if this has some side effects on the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @MadMike: The problem "config files are ignored" occurs using two different DMs and I think this is odd. That's why I asked whether there is some Ubuntu specific configuration I must set before configuring gdm has any effect.

Comment: I know that before lightdm was released gdm would honor the configuration. I don't know why that is.

Comment: The "default" user has no special meaning.  Just be sure that you have another user with sudo rights and you will be good.

Comment: @MadMike: I'm such a rebel I even set a password for root. :-) I'll just delete that user then. Thanks!

Comment: @user1129682 did you try the suggestion in [the other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/215880/158442)? It was necessary for me, and even then only worked after a bug in accountsservice was fixed.

Comment: @muru: You changed these values in `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/adduser.conf` and then, without doing anything else, lightdm honored your `minimum-uid` setting? To answer your question: no, I didn't. I trust MadMike that Ubuntu won't rely on this uid 1000 user anymore and just deleted it.

Comment: @MadMike specifically, `/etc/login.defs`, and I didn't configure anything for `lightdm`. `lightdm` behaviour regarding this is pretty much governed by `accountsservice` now, and `accountsservice` obeyed `login.defs`. Ah well, if the user is deleted..

Comment: I'll recreate it just to try this out ...